# Passing a URL Parameter via a button link

Tags: url, parameter-passing

Very simply, I'm looking for a way to grab the value of a URL parameter and pass this to a target URL inside a button.

Ex:

Page URL: https://example-domain.com/page-1?parameter=value1

In this page, there is a button with the link URL: https://example-domain.com/page-2

I'm looking for a way to have this link to be dynamically updated to https://example-domain.com/page-2?parameter=value1

Is there a way that I can handle without a deep understanding of any coding language for my Wordpress website?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is:

```
<a href="TARGET_URL_HERE" id="ELEMENT_ID_HERE">LINK_TEXT_HERE</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
 var el = document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID_HERE');
 el.href = el.href + window.location.search;
});
</script>
```